# Docker - Failing to get PGP Keys

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a docker build on an existing project.
I am getting this error on one of my steps

```
    Step 3/18 : RUN set -ex   && for key in     9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE   ; do     gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ;   done
 ---> Running in 9e13560f6a4c
+ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 7E37093B from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7E37093B: public key "Christopher Dickinson <christopher.s.dickinson@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
+ gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
gpg: requesting key DBE9B9C5 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
?: pgp.mit.edu: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
+ gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
gpg: requesting key DBE9B9C5 from hkp server keyserver.pgp.com
?: keyserver.pgp.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
+ gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5
gpg: requesting key DBE9B9C5 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
?: ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
Service 'dr-watson' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex   && for key in     9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B     94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5     FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E     71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1     DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D     B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9     C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8     56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE   ; do     gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ||     gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ;   done' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: It looks like your DNS or network connectivity has gone down. Can you lookup those servers outside of a build?

Comment: Yeah I tried pinging those servers but no joy. Tried pinging on https://ping.eu/ping/ but no results are returned there either

Comment: I updated the servers as per https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/Dockerfile.template and this resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the servers as per [github dockerfile template](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/master/Dockerfile.template) and this resolved the issue.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: Hi, @Damien Can you please share the resolution, I am also facing the same issue. Link sent in the answer is broken.

Comment: Here's the [updated link](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/commit/66b46292a6e5dd5856b1d5204dc51547c80eb17a)